# Does Mail() Work on Localhost?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been getting this error every time I use the mail() tag in my project.

```
    Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in 
php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\alex\contact.php on line 75
```

Here is my code:

```
$to = "ahmedmaheratya@gmail.com";

         $subject = "A New Message From" . $email;

         $body = "Here's the Message <br>" . $msg;

         mail($to, $subject, $body, "try@website.com");

        redirestMsg($theMsg, 'back', 900);
```

Is is because I'm on localhost? or is it some typo?

Comment: Your error says it all: Your `sendmail_from` option is not set in php.ini and you're not setting a `From:` header in your `mail` call.

Comment: `mail()` wont work from a Windows machine as there is no MailServer listening for the email you are trying to send. `mail()` itself just passes the email to a mail server to do the actual delivery